# Apache 2.4 module deployment not working

Tags: c++, c, apache, http, httpd.conf

I little new to Apache HTTP 2.4 server and its module development. I have been playing around and created one sample mod_hello.so module to test. But facing the issue while deployment : -

**Issue : -** Not able to deploy the mod_hello.so file in Apache http 2.4 server
Steps performed : -

1. Copied the mod_hello.so file into the /usr/local/apache/modules/
   directory
2. edited the httpd.conf file to load the module :- **LoadModule
   foo_module modules/mod_hello.so**
3. Restarted the httpd service
4. But when i try to access using URL :localhost/foo i get 404
   not found error on browser. In Actual it should produce 'Hello Word'
   Message on browser.
5. In the logs i also checked but couldn't be able to find anything useful

Prior to above activity i have done the following

1. Build the Apache server 2.4 from source and intalled on fedora 15 system
2. For building used APR, APR-UTIL, PCRE
3. Everything went properly and able to compile the sample code and got the desired mod_hello.so file

Any help to debug this issue is highly appreciated

**Logs**

**error_log**

- AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
  qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the
  'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
- AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
  qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the
  'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
- [Wed Nov 12 13:48:17.753498 2014] [core:warn] [pid 13514:tid
  3077613776] AH00098: pid file /usr/local/apache/logs/httpd.pid
  overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

**access_log**

- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:12:58:06 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45
- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:12:58:06 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
  209
- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:12:58:06 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
  209
- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:13:48:24 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45
- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:13:48:32 -0800] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 404 201
- ::1 - - [12/Nov/2014:13:48:34 -0800] "GET /foo HTTP/1.1" 404 201

**Solution**

I have created one fresh conf file in apache/conf/extra/mod_hello.conf and added following lines in it

```
LoadModule helloworld_module modules/libhello.so
<Location /helloworld>
    SetHandler helloworld
</Location>
```

After the above change put added following line into httpd.conf file

```
Include conf/extra/mod_hello.conf
```

Restarted the server

```
./httpd -X
```

Comment: What do your Apache logs say?

Comment: i have added the logs of server in the post please have look

Comment: I am able to solve the issue...please read the solution section of my post.